# Use a list as arg in a TCL procedure

Tags: tcl

I am a beginner in TCL. I am trying to use as the argument of a procedure a list computed beforehand. And I get as a result "invalid command name". here is the code, where am I wrong ?

```
proc matrix_to_quaternion { matrix_VMD } {
  set q1 [expr { 0.5*sqrt(1+[lindex $matrix_VMD 0 0]+[lindex $matrix_VMD 1 1]+[lindex $matrix_VMD 2 2]) }]
  set q2 [expr (1/(4*$q1))*([lindex $matrix_VMD 2 1]-[lindex $matrix_VMD 1 2])]
  set q3 [expr (1/(4*$q1))*([lindex $matrix_VMD 0 2]-[lindex $matrix_VMD 2 0])]
  set q4 [expr (1/(4*$q1))*([lindex $matrix_VMD 1 0]-[lindex $matrix_VMD 0 1])]
  puts q1 q2 q3 q4
  }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a list passed to the command? Also, the `puts` command needs to be invoked as `puts "$q1 $q2 $q3 $q4"` or `puts [list $q1 $q2 $q3 $q4]`.

Comment: Also also, the `puts` command returns the empty string. If you want the `matrix_to_quaternion` command to work as a conversion function you should probably end it with `return [list $q1 $q2 $q3 $q4]`. But without seeing the data you're working with, we can't really advise you.

Comment: The list passed as an argument is of the shape: {{a b c }{d e f }{i j k }{l m n}}

Comment: It's fairly obvious that the list is a 3x3 matrix in two levels, but I need to see your actual numbers to be sure that I'm reproducing your problem. You're assuming that the trace is <=0; if that assumption is wrong you're probably getting a domain error, and so on. I have tried the command with some matrices, but I have yet to get an invalid command name error.

Answer (score 0):

To *return* a compound value (as opposed to just printing it out) you should use something like this:

```
return [list $q1 $q2 $q3 $q4]
```

We use `$` because we want the values in those local variables, not the names of them. You should also put `{`braces`}` around all your expressions as that prevents double-interpolation and allows Tcl to compile your code to go much faster. Here's the correct version:

```
proc matrix_to_quaternion { matrix_VMD } {
    set q1 [expr { 0.5*sqrt(1+[lindex $matrix_VMD 0 0]+[lindex $matrix_VMD 1 1]+[lindex $matrix_VMD 2 2]) }]
    set q2 [expr { (1/(4*$q1))*([lindex $matrix_VMD 2 1]-[lindex $matrix_VMD 1 2]) }]
    set q3 [expr { (1/(4*$q1))*([lindex $matrix_VMD 0 2]-[lindex $matrix_VMD 2 0]) }]
    set q4 [expr { (1/(4*$q1))*([lindex $matrix_VMD 1 0]-[lindex $matrix_VMD 0 1]) }]
    return [list $q1 $q2 $q3 $q4]
}
```

Apart from that, your code fragment is unlikely to produce that error message with sane input data. Not unless you called your code using a code sequence something like this:

```
[matrix_to_quaternion $someInput]
```

In this case, you'd be using the result of the call as a word; the first word of a command is the name of the command, and what you're returning (and what you *should* return in the correct code) is not the name of a command. That makes Tcl complain at you. Tcl's usually careful to try to give you good information about what it thinks is wrong (not just “unknown command” but “unknown command *"BLAH"*”) which can help a lot.

---

The code you've given us confuses me a little though. It's less clear than we might hope. Here's what I'd use (same algorithm) since I'm also aware of the `lassign` command…

```
proc matrix_to_quaternion { matrix_VMD } {
    lassign $matrix_VMD m0 m1 m2
    set q1 [expr { 0.5*sqrt(1 + [lindex $m0 0] + [lindex $m1 1] + [lindex $m2 2]) }]
    set q2 [expr { 0.25/$q1 * ([lindex $m2 1] - [lindex $m1 2]) }]
    set q3 [expr { 0.25/$q1 * ([lindex $m0 2] - [lindex $m2 0]) }]
    set q4 [expr { 0.25/$q1 * ([lindex $m1 0] - [lindex $m0 1]) }]
    return [list $q1 $q2 $q3 $q4]
}
```

It's faster too when I test (it takes about 60% of the time of the version earlier in my answer, and is about 8 times faster than yours after the correction to return the list; bracing expressions makes a *big difference*), but my concern was entirely to do with making the code clearer.